# Brushing and coloring (automatic brushing) with Ggobi and rggobi

Tags: r, graphics, interactive, rggobi

Using the `rggobi` package I launch Ggobi with specified colors:

```
library(rggobi)
g <- ggobi(iris)
clustering <- hclust(dist(iris[,1:4]), meth="average")
classes <- cutree(clustering, 3)
glyph_colour(g[1]) <- classes
```

[image]

When I select a yellow point with the brush, then all the yellow points are active:

[image]

This is, I assume, the expected behavior. But when I select a red point, there are still some remaining non-active red points:

[image]

Is it a bug ? Is there something to do to get the expected behavior ?

### Update

Mmmm.. actually this is *not* the expected behaviour : this is not what we get by running the automatic brushing in Ggobi by selecting a variable.. I'm pursuing my investigations

Answer (score 1):

There's no bug actually, I did something bad. The behaviour shown in my question occurred because I had selected a variable (`Species` in the `iris` dataset) as the identifier variable for the brushing. Thus, when selecting one point, all points belonging to the same level of this variable were activated.

I can delete this thread... though there's no cost to keep it.